# Case insensitive busca Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Estou usando o searhcview da toolbar para fazer pesquisas de itens do recyclerview a busca funciona, porém a query do Firebase diferencia maiúsculo e minusculo e palavras acentuadas. 
Gostaria que fosse Case insensitive busca pelo Firebase.

Ex: Pesquisei a palavra São Paulo e digitei na busca sao paulo.

No recyclerview eu gostaria que aparecesse a palavra São Paulo com maiúsculo e também com ã.

Do modo que a minha query está só aparece São Paulo se eu colocar na busca a palavra São Paulo.

```
 Query Q = organizacao.orderByChild("nomeOrganizacao").
 startAt(newText).endAt(newText + "\uf8ff");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

De momento o Firebase não tem como fazer buscas case insensitive. Mas uma alternativa para você ter o resultado desejado seria: Adicionar um segundo campo que guarde o nome da Organização tudo em minúsculo:

```
"01":{
    "nomeOrganizacao":"São Paulo",
    "nomeMinusculo":"são paulo",
    ...
}
```

E na hora de buscar os dados, você transforma a String que vem da SearchView para minúsculo e faz a query através desse campo:

```
newText = newText.toLowerCase();
Query Q = organizacao.orderByChild("nomeMinusculo").
 startAt(newText).endAt(newText + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: Se esta resposta foi útil, talvez queira clicar no botão de votar à esquerda dela. Se ela respondeu à sua questão, talvez queira [aceitá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Assim os outros saberão que você foi (minimamente) ajudado. Mais detalhes: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)